# Office (365, Powerpoint, Excel, Word): Put "Open file location" in Quick Access Toolbar and/or keyboard shortcut

Tags: excel, ms-word, office365, powerpoint, ms-office

I use the button "Open file location" from File -> Info a lot, in both Powerpoint, Excel, and Word programs (likely any Office(365) program).

Is there a way to make this function available through Quick Access Toolbar and/or keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Comment: OK, I thought that it might be necessary to use VBA code or similar.

Comment: Still off-topic. This site is for questions about existing projects. It's not a place for brain-storming or "ideas" site and it's not a free macro-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I've not found any macro or Word command equivalent to this which is annoying as I use this many times a day.

However, I created the following Word VBA macro to do this:  (Add reference to Microsoft Scripting |Runtime)

```
Sub OpenFolderWhereDocumentSaved()
 Dim filesystem As New FileSystemObject
 Folder = filesystem.GetParentFolderName(Application.ActiveDocument.FullName) & "\"
 Shell "explorer " & Folder, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

This works well for most cases.

However, the problem with this method is that if your document is a SharePoint/One Drive synced file then it uses the SharePoint address so opens in your browser which might not be ideal.

I've not found a way to get the actual local file location, I cannot find a property accessible in Word VBA for the local file, it seems as soon as you open a cloud-file the reported name is that web-address with Word keeping the data we need to itself...

Comment: Also post at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-open-file-location-keyboard-shortcut/7e85c8c3-cd02-40e5-b834-63d2af998a51

Comment: Thanks! Could you please also explain how to get a Quick Access Toolbar Icon or a Keyboard Shortcut out of it?